# Is there a way to parse multiple xml using XMLPullParser?

Tags: java, blackberry, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm reading XML data on a socket. But this socket returns multiple XML documents, now I'm having a trouble parsing all the output. How am I going to parse those XML using XMLPullParser? I'm thinking to have it on a loop but how am I going to know the number of XML documents the socket returns?

This is the piece of my code where I parse the XMLDocument. the `iWbParser` is an object which `extends` `XmlPullParser`.

```
 while (iWbParser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
       if(iWbParser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
             int nextTag = iWbParser.getMappedValue();
             switch(nextTag){
                 ...
             }
       }

 }
```

On the while loop I want to add a condition which will continue the loop until all the number of XML Document is parsed.

This is the code where I read the data from the socket. This is a client socket where I send request to a server and I expect response, which are the xml document.

```
HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
httpConnection = establishConnectionType(httpConnection, loginURL);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/vnd.wv.csp.wbxml");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + requestCommand.length);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept",  "application/vnd.wv.csp.wbxml");
httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
OutputStream out = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
out.write(requestCommand);

if (httpConnection.getResponseCode()== HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
    InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
    iResponseData = readInputStream(is);
}

httpConnection.close();
return iResponseData;
```

`iResponseData` is a byte[] which contains the XML Document which I pass to the parser above.

Comment: Please show us some of the code you're using.  That will help us give you a more specific answer.  Is your one socket getting multiple XML documents, *interleaved* (where one document starts coming across, before the last one has completed)?  Or do you just have **1..N** XML documents coming in, and you don't know what **N** is?

Comment: I have 1..N xml and i don't know what N is.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  But, can you show us the code you use to pull data off the socket?  You probably create some `InputStream` or something, and read from it?  Also, is this socket a **client** socket?  In other words, does it initiate a connection to a **server** that provides XML responses?  Is there an end to the stream of XML responses, or is your code supposed to keep processing new XML documents *forever*?

Comment: Yes it is a client socket where I send a request to the server and expect a response from it. The parsing stops once a certain response is parsed. The response contains 1..N xml document. The code above works properly if the response contains just 1 xml document, but if it contains more than one, the code doesn't parse the other xml.

Comment: are you still looking for a solution for this?

Comment: not anymore. It turns out that the bug that I was fixing is not related to this. But it could help other users if this question is answered.